# MVC putting methods in correct file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I learning MVC model. I looking for some important information. I know that divide program into 3 parts: Model View Controller. In model have we only Class with fields? I still think where to put for example a method:

```
public List<GrowerPickingList> getPalletDetailsDataByGrowerAndPickDate(string grower, DateTime pickDate)
{
        var linqData = from p in this.GrowerPickingList where p.PickDate == pickDate && p.Grower == grower select p;
        return linqData.ToList();
}
```

Should it rather be in Controller or in Model?
Controller is to interact with View but Controller should take data from Model?
I've read some information about it. Some indicates that put into Controller but some to the model. I want to be sure that I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Model-View-Controller is a UI technology. All the Model is supposed to do is carry data from Controller to View and vice versa.

What you show is business logic, which should be in its own layer. Your controller talks to the business layer and translates the returned business models to viewmodels.

Comment: so in Model is used only for carrying? Just properties and constructors?

Comment: That is all you _should_ use a ViewModel for, yes. Many tutorials show otherwise for simplicity, but you shouldn't want to use BusinessModels or DataModels as ViewModels.